# How to get image from a docker repo for test kitchen

Tags: docker, chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen, inspec

I need to test my application with Docker Image httpd and when i add it to the current .kitchen.yaml file it fails with the error:

---

```
root@ip-172-31-1-22:~/test1# kitchen test
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.23.2)
-----> Cleaning up any prior instances of <default-httpd>
-----> Destroying <default-httpd>...
       Finished destroying <default-httpd> (0m0.00s).
-----> Testing <default-httpd>
-----> Creating <default-httpd>...
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: 1 actions failed.
>>>>>>     Create failed on instance <default-httpd>.  Please see       .kitchen/logs/default-httpd.log for more details
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

root@ip-172-31-1-22:~/test1#

---

My Kitchen.yaml file

```
driver:
  name: docker
  use_sudo: false
  #image: httpd

provisioner:
  hosts: aws
  name: ansible_playbook
  #roles_path: roles
  require_ansible_repo: true
  ansible_verbose: true
  ansible_version: latest
  require_chef_for_busser: false
  playbook: default.yml

verifier:
 name: inspec

platforms:
  #- name: ubuntu
  - name: httpd
    driver_config:
      run_command: /bin/systemd
      privileged: true
provision_command:
        - systemctl enable sshd.service

suites:
  - name: default
    verifier:
      inspec_tests:
        - path: /root/kitchen/test/integration/default/test.rb
```

Use Case:

```
1> Deoloy a Httpd base container 
2> Use Ansible Play book to move a index.html file
3> Use ansible tos tart and stop the services 
4> Run an inspec to check if the tests are successful
```

What is the right procedure to deploy an httpd using kitchen.yaml and to test the use case.

```
1> Is this the correct Approch??
2> Should i simply write a Ansible playbook to install httpd and then move my html files.
3> If the Answer to Q2 is yes, then doesn't it defeat the purpose of having an httpd Container already
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are using ansible, then use [`docker` modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_docker.html) to deploy `httpd`